# Is it possible to use SQL Loader for a PostgreSQL database?

Tags: oracle, postgresql, sql-loader

Is there a way to work with SQL Loader for a PostgreSQL database or is it for Oracle Databases only?

Comment: If you are looking for something similar, have a look at [pgloader](https://pgloader.io/)

Answer (score 2):

SQL*Loader is an Oracle utility that uses an oracle client/oracle call interface to talk to an Oracle Database ONLY.